# Make an AJAX request successful with Charles

Tags: jquery, charles-proxy

I am trying to submit an AJAX request with JQuery. For reasons I do not have a valid API key, however, I want to test what happens if the message is successful in my response. I tried using Charles to overwrite the status code to '200', however, jQuery still detects an error. Any insight on how `jQUery.ajax` determines that there is an error what I can overwrite in Charles to have 'success'?

```
var api_key=document.getElementById("api_key").value
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.testapi.com/api/update',
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
         'Authorization': 'Bearer '+api_key,
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: dataFile[index],
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
        if (dataFile[index+1]!=null)
        {
            sendUpdateRequest(dataFile,index+1)
        }
    },
    error: function(data){


        debugger;
        alert("Error: "+data.status)
    }
})
```

Comment: You can't make  a post or set request headers with jsonp request. Use a proxy on server you control or third party service

Comment: I would guess either the content-type was wrong or the body was bad jsonp. This is the response I'm talking about.